# Where to find the full documentation for tcp.h?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

The Kernel has some nice TCP statistics capabilities in `tcp.h`. For example, one can obtain the round trip time (RTT) of the previous TCP communication by reading from `tcpi_rtt`.

However, [not all of these metrics are documented](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/include/uapi/linux/tcp.h#L241) in `tcp.h`. Where can I find the full documentation for all the metrics from `tcp.h`?

For example, what exactly does `tcpi_snd_ssthresh` record?

Comment: It's open source SW so I wouldn't start with the expectation that there is good or even any documentation. Having said that probably your best bet is the [tcp man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/tcp.7.html).

Comment: `Where can I find the full documentation for all the metrics from tcp.h?` ? What if there is no documentation? Read the source code and find out.

Comment: @kaylum Unfortunately, a quick lookup in the man page reveals that no `tcpi_*` are mentioned. I don't really get the point, I would expect Linux to be as well documented as possible. It seems to me like a relatively transparent development process.

Comment: @KamilCuk Thank you. However, my question is exactly about whether the documentation exists or not.

Comment: Then your best bet is to ask the [maintainer](https://www.kernel.org/doc/linux/MAINTAINERS) of the tcp stack.

Comment: @KamilCuk Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: Then the answer is no or very unlikely. It is unrealistic to think that every aspect of an open source project will be documented in detail. The reality is that coders will write lots of code and only document very little of it. That's the same even in paid environments. So if you want to find the info you'll need to sleuth a bit. In this case for example, search for `ssthresh` in the man page. And of course reading the source is the ultimate (but difficult and time consuming) way to find that info.

Comment: @kaylum Thanks for the suggestion. That indeed is my best bet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Where can I find the full documentation for all the metrics from tcp.h?

I believe you have found the "full documentation" already in the source code. More documentation if any will be in [documentation/](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/networking) directory inside sources, but the best way is to ask the maintainer.

> what exactly does tcpi_snd_ssthresh record?

Let's first search [tcpi_snd_ssthresh on elixir](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/A/ident/tcpi_snd_ssthresh), we find out [single assignment of the member](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/net/ipv4/tcp.c#L3445), we then go to [struct tcp::snd_ssthresh](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/linux/tcp.h#L285), and I also seen [this comment above this assigment](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/net/ipv4/tcp.c#L439) mentioning the `draft-stevens-tcpca-spec-01`. From search google for `draft-stevens-tcpca-spec-01` I found [this github repo](https://github.com/credil/ietf-drafts-sorted/tree/master/stevens) that [in this rfc2001.txt](https://github.com/credil/ietf-drafts-sorted/blob/master/stevens/rfc2001.txt) explains the "slow start algorithm" - `ssthresh` is one of the parameters of the algorithm.

Comment: Thanks for citing Elixir and walking me through the process that you use.